# Regarding Needs to create an Index on MongoDB for $lookup query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 3 different collections which has build relation with the another field then primary id.

For ex, I have users, educations and user profiles 3 different collection and users and educations have relation with key user_id of user and same for userinfo. please find sample data.

```
let users = [
    { _id: ObjectId("1"), user_id: 1, name: "Nitin", is_active: true, is_deleted: false },
    { _id: ObjectId("2"), user_id: 2, name: "Vishal", is_active: true, is_deleted: false },
]

let educations =
    [
        { _id: ObjectId("33"), user: 1, std: "10", is_active: true, is_deleted: false },
        { _id: ObjectId("44"), user: 2, std: "8", is_active: true, is_deleted: false },
    ]
let userinfo = [
    { _id: ObjectId("33"), user: 1, weight: "50", is_active: true, is_deleted: false },
    { _id: ObjectId("44"), user: 2, weight: "45", is_active: true, is_deleted: false },
]
```

Now I would like to fetch the relation data and created query by using $lookup by following way.

```
let criteria = {
    is_active: true,
    is_deleted: false,
};
const result = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('users').aggregate([
    //education
    { $lookup: { from: "education", localField: "user_id", foreignField: "user", as: "education" } },
    { $unwind: { path: "$education", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    //userinfo
    { $lookup: { from: "userinfo", localField: "user_id", foreignField: "user", as: "userinfo" } },
    { $unwind: { path: "$userinfo", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    { $match: { is_deleted: false } },

    { $match: criteria },
    {
        "$facet": {
            "totalLocation": [
                { $match: criteria },
                { "$count": "count" },
            ],
            
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "totalLocation": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$totalLocation.count", 0] },
        }
    }
], { allowDiskUse: true, collation: { locale: 'en_US', alternate: "shifted" } }).toArray();
```

This query works completely fine and return data as expected. But now as data are growing so this query became slower and we would make it faster. one of solution which I found that to **create an index** in a way so we can have faster result. I have tried but it doesn't works for me

so can anyone help me to **create a index** on this kind of query. or any another solution.

Explanation as requested in comment

```
{
"stages" : [ 
    {
        "$cursor" : {
            "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "mydata.users",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                    "is_deleted" : {
                        "$eq" : false
                    }
                },
                "queryHash" : "242D9E6F",
                "planCacheKey" : "386E80BB",
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                    "transformBy" : {
                        "cb_id" : 1,
                        "user" : 1,
                        "_id" : 0
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "is_deleted" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : []
            },
            "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 2328,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 265,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 2355,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                    "nReturned" : 2328,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                    "works" : 2357,
                    "advanced" : 2328,
                    "needTime" : 28,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 3,
                    "restoreState" : 3,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "transformBy" : {
                        "cb_id" : 1,
                        "user" : 1,
                        "_id" : 0
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "is_deleted" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 2328,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 2357,
                        "advanced" : 2328,
                        "needTime" : 28,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 3,
                        "restoreState" : 3,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "docsExamined" : 2355
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : NumberLong(2328),
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(20)
    },
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "education",
            "as" : "education",
            "localField" : "user_id",
            "foreignField" : "user",
            "unwinding" : {
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : NumberLong(2328),
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(136)
    }, 
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "userinfo",
            "as" : "userinfo",
            "localField" : "user_id",
            "foreignField" : "user",
            "unwinding" : {
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : NumberLong(2328),
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(264)
    }, 
    {
        "$facet" : {
            "totalLocation" : [ 
                {
                    "$teeConsumer" : {},
                    "nReturned" : NumberLong(2328),
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(264)
                }, 
                {
                    "$group" : {
                        "_id" : {
                            "$const" : null
                        },
                        "count" : {
                            "$sum" : {
                                "$const" : 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : NumberLong(1),
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(264)
                }, 
                {
                    "$project" : {
                        "count" : true,
                        "_id" : false
                    },
                    "nReturned" : NumberLong(1),
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(264)
                }
            ]
        },
        "nReturned" : NumberLong(1),
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(264)
    }, 
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : true,
            "totalLocation" : {
                "$arrayElemAt" : [ 
                    "$totalLocation.count", 
                    {
                        "$const" : 0.0
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : NumberLong(1),
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberLong(264)
    }
],
"serverInfo" : {},
"ok" : 1.0
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `user` field in the `education` and `userInfo` collections? Can you edit the question to include or link the the `.explain("executionStats")` output?

Comment: yes i have indexes

Comment: Please _show_ us that, along with other debugging information we need to assist, by gathering the requested `.explain("executionStats")` output for the query. Otherwise you are stating that you want help creating indexes but that the indexes already exist, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: @user20042973 please review udpated question

Comment: Thanks, a few questions. What version are you using? `serverInfo` is empty. Either way, the operation took 264 milliseconds, what's the expected runtime? The `$unwind` stages do not appear to be changing the number of documents - is the `user` field in `education` and `userinfo` unique? Is this a modified version of the actual pipeline? Right now it basically looks like an expensive way to count the number of `users` who are not deleted (`is_deleted: false`)